# Find matches in strings in columns

Tags: python, pandas

I stuck on using regex while trying to match columns.

I need to match the strings from columns 1 and 2 with column 3. If there's full math, put the 1 in column4. The problem is that strings in column 1 and column 3 can be upper or/and lower case, contain symbols, have whitespace between words etc.

Input:

```
 column1        | column2  | column3                  
BankWarehouse   |  GR      | BANK_WAREHOUSE, GR      
Bank_Warehouse  |  TU      | Tu, Bank Warehouse     
Bank Warehouse  |  TU      | Bank_Warehouse_GR      
BankWarehouse   |  GR      | BankWarehouse_gr
```

Here is an output with the expected column 4:

```
 column1        | column2  | column3                  | column4
BankWarehouse   |  GR      | BANK_WAREHOUSE, GR       |     1
Bank_Warehouse  |  TU      | Tu, Bank Warehouse       |     1
Bank Warehouse  |  TU      | Bank_Warehouse_GR        |     0
BankWarehouse   |  GR      | BankWarehouse_gr         |     1
```

Is there a way to deal with it without using regex? As it completely blew my mind...

Comment: kindly add ur expected output. dataframe as well

Comment: What if there are more characters in the column 3? For instance  "BANK_WAREHOUSE, GR hello" in the first row of the example you posted? Is it a match or not?

Comment: What have you actually tried? Even if it failed, explain your reasoning so far. We're here to help you work through your problems, not do them for you.

Comment: @SreeramTP yep, there can be another words / letters / symbols. considering your example, it's a match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I will go about it:

```
df["column4"] = df.apply(
    lambda x: (
        re.sub(r"[^a-zA-Z+]", "", (x.column1 + x.column2).strip().lower())
        in re.sub(r"[^a-zA-Z+]", "", x.column3.strip().lower())
    )
    or (
        re.sub(r"[^a-zA-Z+]", "", (x.column2 + x.column1).strip().lower())
        in re.sub(r"[^a-zA-Z+]", "", x.column3.strip().lower())
    ),
    axis=1,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want you can work in a easily (but probably not nice-to-see) way:
create a column joining rows from col1 and col2, and clean it from punctuation. Then clean also col3 and try matching.

Do you have to keep the rows the way they are? or can you change something?